# What happens at server/endpoint level when client internet connection is lost while the HTTP POST request is executing?

Tags: jquery, http, post, tcp, upload

I have a POST endpoint that uploads file into cloud storage by invoking an api.

The code in the endpoint is:

1. Get the file from the POST request
2. Save it in a local folder
3. Invoke cloud storage POST api to send the file into the cloud storage (example: aws s3)
4. Delete the file from local storage
5. Return success/failure response

I understand there is a 3-way TCP handshake (and TLS upgrade if using the secure https protocol) for http connection establishment.

Suppose the client has invoked the POST endpoint and the client looses connection when the process has reached step 3 (assume it takes 20 seconds for step 3 to complete and the client looses connection at the 5th second), then:

1. Will the endpoint execution detect that the client connection has dropped and abort the step 3?
2. In a second or two, suppose the client gets back the internet, then will the client be able to get the response?
3. Same as above, but upon internet re-establishment suppose client gets a new IP, then will client be able to get the response?

Answer (score 0):

> Will the endpoint execution detect that the client connection has dropped and abort the step 3?

This depends on the server side implementation. Depending on how the connection was dropped and how long step 3 takes the server might not even realize that it has dropped before step 3 is finished.

A properly implemented server will realize though if the request is complete or not and will not even start with step 3 if the request (and therefore the uploaded file) is incomplete.

> In a second or two, suppose the client gets back the internet, then will the client be able to get the response?

HTTP is build on top of a reliable transport, either TCP (HTTP/1 and HTTP/2) or QUIC (HTTP/3). Short connection drops which result in small packet loss are dealt at this level and the connection will transparently continue from the perspective of HTTP as if nothing has happened.

> Same as above, but upon internet re-establishment suppose client gets a new IP, then will client be able to get the response?

More serious connection drops which lead to the breakage of the underlying TCP/QUIC connection will make it impossible for the current request to transparently continue, i.e. the client will not be able to get the response to the original request. Changing client IP address is one of such cases but not the only one.

If the application needs to deal with such irregularities than it needs a more robust design. This might be done by splitting the file upload into multiple stages and thus multiple requests, like one for starting an upload transaction, others for uploading parts of the file inside this transactions and finally a request to query the status of the transaction, i.e. if the file was successfully uploaded to the cloud storage.

Comment: Assuming the step 3 takes 20 seconds to complete and the client looses connection at step 3 at the 5th second, then will the server code continue execution or abort? I'm not sure why at all (if it does?) it must abort because only at step 5 it tries to send response back to the client, at which point server may realize that client is not reachable.